# QueryException SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.4

i learn foreign key in laravel for the first time .. i have this message error when i insert data on the form to table . i think my table is fine. can u tell me how to solve this ?

Controller :

```
public function tambah(Request $request){
    $a = new Admin;
    $this->validate($request, ['nama'=>'required|unique:ab']);
    $a->id = $request->id;
    $a->nama = $request->nama;
    $a->save();

    return redirect()->to('admin/data_desa')->with('success','Data berhasil ditambahkan');
}


}
```

table :

```
 class CreateDesasTable extends Migration
 {
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    //
    Schema::dropIfExist('desas');
    Schema::create('desas', function(Blueprint $table){
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('nama');

});
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    //
    Schema::dropIfExist('desas');

}
}
```

Route :

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function(){
Route::group(['prefix' => 'tanitani'], function(){
    Route::get('admin', 'AdminController@index');
    Route::get('admin/data_desa','AdminController@tampil');
    Route::post('admin/data_desa', 'AdminController@tambah');
```

Comment: please add the actual error to the post

Answer (score 2):

You have tou override the table name ih the `Admin` model, since you have a different table name.

**Why ?**

Because by convetion Laravel will assume that the table name is `admins`.

So add this line to your model :

```
protected $table = 'desas';
```

Comment: i have to adding it . but not work. i still have the same message error @Maraboc

Comment: did you migrate the database to create the table in the first place ?

Comment: i dont know mean of the first place ...is a relation table in database ? im sorry :(( im new in laravel.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not working with laravel eloquent model conventions.

Are you sure that model `Admin` is the model that you are required to save `desas` data in your controller?

if the answer is true update model Admin with

```
protected $table = 'desas';
```

**Recommendation**: Try to use the same name convention between models and database tables.

See https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions for more information.

**Recommended docs before continue:**

- https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations
- https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue, simply check the migration file, the name of the table needs to be plural 
when I search:

```
App\post::all();
Table 'laravel.posts' doesn't exist (SQL: select * * from `posts`)'
```

so change create it all again make:migration create_posts_table
run the command and migrate. then:

```
App\posts::all();
```

It worked for me.